# Exporting data from a Google Sheets sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I've created a spreadsheet in Google Sheets for employees to create something called a Project Code. Expenses and reimbursements are given a Project Code for tracking.

On our server we have Excel documents for reimbursements and expense tracking. And I've been asked to link these documents to the Project Codes in Google Sheets.

The way I was planning to do it was spit out the Project Codes into a CSV on our server and point the reimbursements and expense Excel files to the CSV. The plan was to update the CSV automatically whenever a new Project Code is created.

BUT, JavaScript in Google Sheets isn't allowed to write directly to my computer, from what I have gathered.

So, I am looking for workarounds, which need to be automated as there isn't anyone available to keep the Project Code reference CSV file manually updated.

Is there a way, with JavaScript to ask the user for permission to download a file?

Could I create the file on Google Drive and download this to the computer?

Thanx in advance, James

Comment: Yes you can. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Noogui...sorry I'm just responding, I didn't see your response, I dodn't get a heads up from Stack. I asked a few questions, so what are you saying 'yes' to? When you say "tried", the question is what can I try? All my research indicates I can't write directly to someone's drive, plus I didn't see any JS / Google Sheet API functions that would allow me to do so.